# Greater/lesser statements malfunction in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, basic

I am trying to run a loop in VBA with the following statement:

```
...
If Range("K" & h).Value >= mingreen Then
...
```

h starts at 4, and the value of K4 is 0.75 (but it's derived from a formula). mingreen is 0.5. So the statement should be true. But somehow it returns false. Actually, when a cell is a formula it seems the >= statement is not working at all. Why is that and is there any way to get around it?

Comment: What data type is `mingreen`? Variant, Double? Have you tried using `Value2` instead of `Value`?

Comment: Can you post the type of `minigreen`, and the formula you're using? I was able to run this on my Excel and it worked (note: `minigreen` is an `Integer`, `Dim minigreen as Integer: minigreen = .5`).  Make sure `h` is also an `Integer`.  When I used this line it works: `If Range("K" & 4).Value >= minigreen Then debug.print "True!"`, again this is with `Dim minigreen as Integer`.

Comment: @BruceWayne - Why are you testing using integers when he has floating-point values? `Double` would be a better choice. Your `minigreen = .5` is just going to become `0`.

Comment: You need to provide more context. It is impossible for us to tell, based on what you have shown, why the code isn't working the way that you think it should work. Psychic debugging is hard.

Comment: @Bond - I would do that because I wasn't thinking :P. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Sorry guys for the late reply - was away from any machines later that day. I've found out what happened - I declared them as Variant, and when I changed it to Double it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct book and sheet and try `value2`:

```
If (Thisworkbook.sheets("nameOfSheet").Range("K" & h).Value2 >= mingreen) Then
```